# Producing an view of a text's revision history in Python

Tags: python, diff, history, revision

I have two versions of a piece of text and I want to produce an HTML view of its revision similar to what Google Docs or Stack Overflow displays.  I need to do this in Python.  I don't know what this technique is called but I assume that it has a name and hopefully there is a Python library that can do it.

Version 1:

> William Henry "Bill" Gates III (born
>   October 28, 1955)[2] is an American
>   business magnate, philanthropist, and
>   chairman[3] of Microsoft, the software
>   company he founded with Paul Allen.

Version 2:

> William Henry "Bill" Gates III (born
>   October 28, 1955)[2] is a business
>   magnate, philanthropist, and
>   chairman[3] of Microsoft, the software
>   company he founded with Paul Allen. 
>   He is American.

The desired output:

> William Henry "Bill" Gates III (born
>   October 28, 1955)[2] is a<strike>n American</strike> business
>   magnate, philanthropist, and
>   chairman[3] of Microsoft, the software
>   company he founded with Paul Allen.
>   ***He is American.***

Using the diff command doesn't work because it tells me which lines are different but not which columns/words are different.

```
$ echo 'William Henry "Bill" Gates III (born October 28, 1955)[2] is an American business magnate, philanthropist, and chairman[3] of Microsoft, the software company he founded with Paul Allen.' > oldfile
$ echo 'William Henry "Bill" Gates III (born October 28, 1955)[2] is a business magnate, philanthropist, and chairman[3] of Microsoft, the software company he founded with Paul Allen.  He is American.' > newfile
$ diff -u oldfile newfile
--- oldfile 2010-04-30 13:32:43.000000000 -0700
+++ newfile 2010-04-30 13:33:09.000000000 -0700
@@ -1 +1 @@
-William Henry "Bill" Gates III (born October 28, 1955)[2] is an American business magnate, philanthropist, and chairman[3] of Microsoft, the software company he founded with Paul Allen.
+William Henry "Bill" Gates III (born October 28, 1955)[2] is a business magnate, philanthropist, and chairman[3] of Microsoft, the software company he founded with Paul Allen.  He is American.' > oldfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Diff Merge Patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) has a pretty good diff implementation in pure python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wdiff](http://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/).  I don't know if there's a Python implementation:

```
$ wdiff oldfile newfile
William Henry "Bill" Gates III (born October 28, 1955)[2] is [-an American-] {+a+} business magnate, philanthropist, and chairman[3] of Microsoft, the software company he founded with Paul Allen.  {+He is American.+}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) module might be of assistance with this problem.